# what are the different plug-ins need to access web cam images of client browser in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, webclient, webcam, client-side

I am doing project which i need every `random time` I want to `capture images` from client side and send to server side.

My question is what are simple choice for access web cam image from client browser
i know only

1. flash
2. Silver light

regarding this two if any simple way to access web cam images please provide

Comment: There is nothing that will just _hand_ you web cam images from the browsers of your users. Your users can _send_ you webcam images, but you cannot _take_ them without explicit user action. Do you have some good reason to take webcam images without the knowledge of the user? Because, you _know_ what this sounds like.

Comment: @John Saunders. What have you said is well. I want user snaps at every random time Because in my project goal is `One member is access to stay at client system` so i want to take every random seconds take the images from browser window

Comment: This will not happen. You cannot spy on people.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [jpegcam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/wiki/Instructions) ,Javascript and Flash library that allows you to enable your users to submit Webcam snapshots to your server in JPEG format.From this [link](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/wiki/Instructions) you can get instruction how to use it.you need to download files and add it to your project.But the server side code given here is php based,for c# take look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579407/jquery-webcam-plugin-save-image-without-php/13284531#13284531) i have posted the answer there.
Hope this help you.