# JQuery webcam plugin with asp.net 4.0, not able to save captured image on server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webcam

I am using JQuery webcam plugin with asp.net 4.0. I want to capture image and save it on server. I reached to the point where I can see webcam, click photo and send it to server side. But I am not understanding how to save that posted image on server.

I tried saving InputStream to the file but it is saying its not valid image. please help.

**aspx code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#webcam").webcam({
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            mode: "save",
            swffile: 'jscam.swf'
        });
    });

    function capture() {
        webcam.capture();
        webcam.save('SavePhoto.aspx');
    }
</script>


<div id="webcam"></div>
<input type="button" id="takePhoto" onclick="capture();" value="Capture" />
```

Comment: just go through this link might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579407/jquery-webcam-plugin-save-image-without-php
There might be problem with code in aspx page where you handle image saving function,post your code where you have functionality to save image

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search I ended up with this solution. Just pass `Request.InputStream` to the function. In my case I have to create a thumbnail copy so I needed `System.Drawing.Image`

```
    Public Function getImage(SrcStream As System.IO.Stream) As System.Drawing.Image
    'This function returns Image from InputStream
    Dim dump As String

    Using reader = New StreamReader(SrcStream)
        dump = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
    ''To save as a file.
    'Dim path = Server.MapPath("/test.jpg")
    'System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, String_To_Bytes2(dump))

    Return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(New System.IO.MemoryStream(String_To_Bytes2(dump)))
End Function

    Private Function String_To_Bytes2(strInput As String) As Byte()
    Dim numBytes As Integer = (strInput.Length) / 2
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(numBytes - 1) {}

    For x As Integer = 0 To numBytes - 1
        bytes(x) = Convert.ToByte(strInput.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)
    Next

    Return bytes
    End Function
```

(hope you can convert it to c#)